# Foreground Text has same filters as background

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So I needed to darken the background on my web app, but need the foreground to still have 100% brightness. Currently my CSS is as follows:

```css
.background {
  background-image: url(./background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  filter: grayscale(30%) brightness(30%);
  font-family: Oswald, sans serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

.name {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 120px;
}

.foreground {
  margin: auto;
  filter: unset;
}
```

```html
<div className="background">
  <div className="foreground">
    <h1 className="name">
      Hello World!
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

My title (in the foreground div, with the class "name") is appearing darkened like the background still, how can I make sure it doesn't follow the same filters as the background?

Comment: can you please add the html as well.

Comment: @SumitPatel done

Comment: If that background not dynamic I would recommend you make changes to that background on any image editor and not use `filter` at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure any of the content you throw in as a child to that outer background is going to inherit the filter - you were on the right track with absolute positioning as a workaround.  Place the foreground on top of the background instead of it inheriting that position through box model logic.

See here:

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/cclark413/pen/mdbVzmr)

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.background {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/200/300");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  filter: grayscale(30%) brightness(30%);
  font-family: Oswald, sans serif;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
}
.foreground {
  width:100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align:center;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:500;
  top:0;
}
.name {
  font-size: 120px;
  color:white !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
</div>
<div class="foreground">
  <div class="name">
    Hello World!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like adding one extra div for background image will give you desire result.

```css
.img {
  background: url('https://c.ndtvimg.com/qqdl3rn8_15-august_625x300_13_August_18.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  filter: grayscale(30%) brightness(30%);
  font-family: Oswald, sans serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

.name {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 120px;
  color: #ff0000;
}

.foreground {
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="img">test</div>
  <div class="foreground">
    <h1 class="name">
      Hello World!
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```